# Meaning of "sensorily"

Tags: meaning, adverbs, archaicisms

As a non-native English speaker, I am having a hard time understanding what the author means by *sensorily austere* here. The quote is taken from *Man in the landscape*, by Paul Shepard.

> The desert is the environment of revelation, genetically  and physiologically alien, sensorily austere, esthetically abstract, historically inimical.
>    [...]

I haven't found a dictionary that lists this word, but possible variations such as *sensory*.

Could anyone give me an easily understandable definition for that context?

(Is this perhaps an old-English word?)

Comment: http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/sensorily contains a few examples and http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sensorily has a clear definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that he means to say that there was not much there for the senses to "pickup". As in "there's not much to look at in a desert."

Answer (score 1):

"Sensorily rich" would mean rich with sensory experience or information: a lot of visual (see), tactile (feel, touch), auditory (hear), olfactory (smell), and gustatory (taste) input. "Sensorily austere" means a lack of this sensory input.